# How to find power delivered by current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

[image]

I need to find power delivered by current source. I tried using node analysis but there is a voltage source and it can't be transformed to current source as there is no resistor in series. Can you tell how to do it?

Comment: Please take sharp photo of your work in focus and rotate it the right side up. Thank you for flagging homework as homework, it's unfortunately uncommon here.

Comment: cvcv, I won't try and read that top photo. But the job boils down to just finding the voltage across the current source. Once you know that, you know the power by multiplying the voltage across the current source by the current source's current (with positive or negative results whose interpretation depends somewhat on what system you use in creating the equations -- passive, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I tried using node analysis but there is a voltage source and it can't
> be transformed to current source as there is no resistor in series*

**HINT** - there's nothing wrong in adding an extra 7 volt source and redrawing like this: -

[image]

Now you can turn both voltage sources to current sources quite visibly easily: -

[image]

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand how you redraw this.

Comment: @cvcv if you applied a short circuit between the positive terminals of the two 7 volt sources, does that make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

*This should be in your book* -- so once you make sense of this answer, go find where they tell you.  Depending on the book, it may just be a half a page, but they shouldn't be asking you if they didn't give you the tools to do it.

In general, you're forcing a node (or the difference in voltages between two nodes) to be the value of the voltage source.

Choose a node and call it ground.  I'm choosing the node at the negative terminal of the 7V source.  You can either label the node at the + end of the 7V source, or you can just take it into account while writing your equations -- I'll treat it like a mysterious unknown voltage, but that won't last long.

Let:

- \$v_7\$ be the voltage at the + side of the voltage source (gee, why the strange nomenclature...)
- \$v_1\$ be the voltage at the junction of the \$1\Omega\$, \$3\Omega\$, and current source.
- \$v_2\$ be the voltage at the junction of the \$1\Omega\$, \$3\Omega\$, and \$2\Omega\$ resistors.

Now write out the equations:

$$\begin{align}
v_7 &= 7\mathrm V \\
\frac 1 {1 \Omega} (v_1 - v_7) + \frac 1 {3 \Omega} (v_1 - v_2) &= 7 \mathrm A \\
\frac 1 {3 \Omega} (v_2 - v_1) + \frac 1 {2 \Omega} (v_2 - v_7) + \frac 1 {1 \Omega} v_2 & = 0 \mathrm A
\end{align}$$

I'm going to leave this for you to make sure the units are consistent, to verify that you have enough equationsn in enough unknowns, and to verify that everything checks out (which I hope, for my own reputation, that they do!).

You should be able to solve this easily from here.

---

Note that I didn't *have* to make the negative end of the 7V source ground --  I could have made some other node ground.  If I had called them \$v_1\$ at the positive end and \$v_2\$ at the negative end, then the constraint equation would have been
$$v_1 - v_2 = 7 \mathrm V$$

Assuming I'd gotten the rest of the circuit translated correctly into math, the results would be exactly the same.